# Difference between Bitmap.FromFile(path) and new Bitmap(path)

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I woud like to know the difference between these two:

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap("C:\\test.bmp");
Bitmap bitmap2 = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\test.bmp");
```

Is one option better than the other one? Does `Bitmap.FromFile(path)` fills in any additional data to the bitmap image or is it just a delegate to `new Bitmap(path)`?

Comment: FWIW you're calling a static method from a derived class, and it's actually `Image.FromFile`. Not that it changes the question.

Answer (score 12):

The 'FromFile' method comes from the abstract base class `Image`, which returns an Image object. Whereas the `Bitmap` class inherits the `Image` class, and the `Bitmap` constructor allows you to initialize `Bitmap` object directly.

In your second line of code, what you are trying to do is call `FromFile()` and get an `Image` object, and then type cast it to `Bitmap`. There's not really a good reason to do this manually, when the bitmap `constructor` can do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Both methods get a handle to the image via the `path` argument. `Image.FromFile` will return the superclass `Image`, while the former will simply return the `Bitmap` so you can avoid the cast.

Internally, they pretty much do the same:

```
public static Image FromFile(String filename,
                                     bool useEmbeddedColorManagement)
{

    if (!File.Exists(filename)) 
    {
        IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(filename);
        throw new FileNotFoundException(filename);
    }

    filename = Path.GetFullPath(filename);

    IntPtr image = IntPtr.Zero;
    int status;

    if (useEmbeddedColorManagement) 
    {
        status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipLoadImageFromFileICM(filename, out image);
    }
    else 
    {
        status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipLoadImageFromFile(filename, out image);
    }

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

    status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipImageForceValidation(new HandleRef(null, image));

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
    {
        SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDisposeImage(new HandleRef(null, image));
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }

    Image img = CreateImageObject(image);
    EnsureSave(img, filename, null);

    return img;
}
```

And:

```
public Bitmap(String filename) 
{
    IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(filename);
    filename = Path.GetFullPath(filename);

    IntPtr bitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

    int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(filename, out bitmap);

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

    status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipImageForceValidation(new HandleRef(null, bitmap));

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok) 
    {
        SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDisposeImage(new HandleRef(null, bitmap));
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }

    SetNativeImage(bitmap);

    EnsureSave(this, filename, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say - internally both method are very close, except that `Image.FromFile()` will check if the file exists and throw a `FileNotFoundException` if this is not the case.

The main difference is that `Bitmap.ctor()` calls `GdipCreateBitmapFromFile` internally while `Image.FromFile()` calls `GdipLoadImageFromFile`;

These Gdip-methods lead to two MSDN articles ([Bitmap.ctor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536316(v=vs.85).aspx) & [Image.FromFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535370(v=vs.85).aspx)) which are pretty close to each other, however the supported file formats seem to differ:

```
Bitmap: BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF
Image:  BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, and EMF.
```

Anyway, if you know that you will have Bitmap, I'd prefer `new Bitmap("C:\\test.bmp")` just to get rid of the need to cast the image afterwards.