# Wrong RGB values in GetPixel() from png image

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

This is the problem:
I save a Bitmap in `.png`  with colors say `ARGB(50,210,102,70)` with dimension `1 x 1 pixel`.

I retrieve the same image again and use the `GetPixel(0,0)` method, what I get is `ARGB(50,209,102,70)`.

There is a slight variation in the retrieved value, the `RGB` values slightly differ but the `A` value remains same.

However when i use `255` for `A` value, the correct `RGB` values are returned.

So,.. Using a value less than `255` for `A` results in the problem mentioned above.

Here is the code which saves the Bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmpPut = new Bitmap(1, 1); //Also tried with 'PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb'
bmpPut.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.FromArgb(254, 220, 210, 70)); 
bmpPut.Save("1.png"); //Also tried with using 'ImageFormat.Png'
```

Here is the code which gets the pixel color

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("1.png"));
MessageBox.Show("R:" + bit.GetPixel(0, 0).R.ToString() +
    "| G: " + bit.GetPixel(0, 0).G.ToString() +
    "| B: " + bit.GetPixel(0, 0).B.ToString() +
    "| A: " + bit.GetPixel(0, 0).A.ToString());
```

What i get is `ARGB(254,219,209,70)`

[image]

**P.S.**: I read a few similar questions, they were'nt addressing this exact issue and I din't find a solution yet.

Comment: Try it without the `Image.FromFile()` part like this: `Bitmap bit = new Bitmap("1.png");`. Worked for me.

Comment: I ll try that and get back!

Comment: Wow, that was pretty simple. Thanks @mammago. It works now!! You could put that as an answer!! so that i can mark it answered!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("1.png"));
```

with

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap("1.png");
```

Should do the trick.
It seems like `Image.FromFile()` isn't as precise as the `Bitmap` constructor.

Comment: is there a explaination for that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't explain that behaviour. If you want to research you could maybe take a look at the implementation of both in the System.Drawing sources. I saw both methods are using different functions in the underlying GDI+ dll but I can't tell you what exactly is going on because I'm not a C++ developer. Source code links to [Bitmap](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,e1ba6ce9c451889d) and [Image](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,3ac4e4b806474215)

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207313/difference-between-bitmap-fromfilepath-and-new-bitmappath) for more links and guesses.. Most likely one uses color management.. both methods have an overload that lets you control it but I found no difference. Not so surprising as no cm was created, I guess.

Comment: This answer and comments piqued my attention, so I decided to investigate a bit. This is actually *totally* bizarre. I can't reproduce this behavior in C++ using the GDI+ API, but I *do* nevertheless see it using the `Graphics` wrapper class provided by the .NET BCL. Still working on trying to pinpoint the difference in the .NET wrappers.

Answer (score 7):

[mammago has found a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242192/366904), namely using the class constructor to construct a `Bitmap` object directly from a file, rather than constructing a `Bitmap` object indirectly via the `Image` object returned by `Image.FromFile()`.

The purpose of this answer is to explain *why* that works, and in particular, what the actual *difference* is between the two approaches that causes different per-pixel color values to be obtained.

One proposal for the difference was color management. However, this appears to be  a non-starter, as neither invocation is asking for color-management (ICM) support.

You can, however, tell a lot by inspecting the source code for the .NET BCL. In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241831/wrong-rgb-values-in-getpixel-from-png-image#comment69684362_41242192), mammago posted links to the code for the [`Image`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs) and [`Bitmap`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs) class implementations, but wasn't able to discern the relevant differences.

Let's start with the [`Bitmap` class constructor that creates a `Bitmap` object directly from a file](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,8f37ac8955882480,references), since that's the simplest:

```
public Bitmap(String filename) {
    IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(filename);

    // GDI+ will read this file multiple times.  Get the fully qualified path
    // so if our app changes default directory we won't get an error
    filename = Path.GetFullPath(filename);

    IntPtr bitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

    int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(filename, out bitmap);

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

    status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipImageForceValidation(new HandleRef(null, bitmap));

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok) {
        SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDisposeImage(new HandleRef(null, bitmap));
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }

    SetNativeImage(bitmap);

    EnsureSave(this, filename, null);
}
```

Lots of stuff going on there, but most of it is not relevant. The first bits of code simply obtain and validate the path. After that is the important bit: a call to the native GDI+ function, `GdipCreateBitmapFromFile`, one of [the many Bitmap-related functions provided by the GDI+ flat API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/ms533971.aspx). It does exactly what you would think, it creates a `Bitmap` object from a path to an image file without using color matching (ICM). This is the function that does the heavy lifting. The .NET wrapper then checks for errors and validates the resulting object again. If validation fails, it cleans up and throws an exception. If validation succeeds, it saves the handle in a member variable (the call to `SetNativeImage`), and then calls a function (`EnsureSave`) that does nothing unless the image if a GIF. Since this one isn't, we'll ignore that completely.

Okay, so conceptually, this is just a big, expensive wrapper around `GdipCreateBitmapFromFile` that performs a bunch of redundant validation.

What about `Image.FromFile()`? Well, [the overload you're actually calling](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,cd75f3ae060b69f3,references) is just a stub that forwards to [the other overload](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,f7cc7221ba00597a,references), passing `false` to indicate that color matching (ICM) is not desired. The code for the interesting overload is as follows:

```
public static Image FromFile(String filename,
                             bool useEmbeddedColorManagement) {
    if (!File.Exists(filename)) {
        IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(filename);
        throw new FileNotFoundException(filename);
    }

    // GDI+ will read this file multiple times.  Get the fully qualified path
    // so if our app changes default directory we won't get an error
    filename = Path.GetFullPath(filename);

    IntPtr image = IntPtr.Zero;
    int status;

    if (useEmbeddedColorManagement) {
        status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipLoadImageFromFileICM(filename, out image);
    }
    else {
        status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipLoadImageFromFile(filename, out image);
    }

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

    status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipImageForceValidation(new HandleRef(null, image));

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok) {
        SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDisposeImage(new HandleRef(null, image));
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }

    Image img = CreateImageObject(image);

    EnsureSave(img, filename, null);

    return img;
}
```

This looks very much the same. It validates the file name in a slightly different way, but that isn't failing here, so we can ignore these differences. If embedded color management was not requested, it delegates to another native GDI+ flat API function to do the heavy lifting: [`GdipLoadImageFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041.aspx).

[Others have speculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208101/366904) that the difference may be a result of these two different native functions. It's a good theory, but I disassembled these functions, and though they have distinct implementations, there are no salient differences that would account for the behavior observed here. `GdipCreateBitmapFromFile` will perform validation, attempt to load a metafile if possible, and then call down to the constructor for an internal `GpBitmap` class to do the actual loading. `GdipLoadImageFromFile` is implemented similarly, except that it arrives at the `GpBitmap` class constructor indirectly via the internal `GpImage::LoadImage` function. Furthermore, I was unable to reproduce the behavior you described by calling these native functions directly in C++, so that eliminates them as candidates for an explanation.

Interestingly, I was also unable to reproduce the behavior you describe by casting the result of `Image.FromFile` to a `Bitmap`, e.g.:

```
Bitmap bit = (Bitmap)(Image.FromFile("1.png"));
```

Although not a good idea to rely on it, you can see that this is actually legal if you go back to the source code for `Image.FromFile`. It calls [the internal `CreateImageObject` function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,e328c776c1ca78db), which delegates either to `Bitmap.FromGDIplus` to `Metafile.FromGDIplus` according to the actual type of the image being loaded. [The `Bitmap.FromGDIplus` function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,cefcecf32e747f14,references) just constructs a `Bitmap` object, calls the `SetNativeImage` function we have already seen to set its underlying handle, and returns that `Bitmap` object. Therefore, when you load a bitmap image from a file, `Image.FromFile` actually returns a `Bitmap` object. And this `Bitmap` object behaves identically to one created using the `Bitmap` class constructor.

The key to reproducing the behavior is to create a *new* `Bitmap` object based on the result of `Image.FromFile`, which is what exactly your original code did:

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("1.png"));
```

This will call [the `Bitmap` class constructor that takes an `Image` object](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,c22df1c3cf79e816,references), which delegates internally to [one that takes explicit dimensions](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,687e85c43e9a2c42,references):

```
public Bitmap(Image original, int width, int height) : this(width, height) {
    Graphics g = null;
    try {
        g = Graphics.FromImage(this);
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        g.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
    finally {
        if (g != null) {
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And *here* is where we finally find an explanation for the behavior you describe in the question! You can see that **it creates a temporary `Graphics` object from the specified `Image` object, fills the `Graphics` object with a transparent color, and finally draws a copy of the specified `Image` into that `Graphics` context. At this point, it is *not* the same image you're working with, but a *copy* of that image.** This is where color matching can kick in, as well as a variety of other things that potentially affect the image.

**In fact, aside from the unexpected behavior described in the question, the code you had written hid a bug**: it fails to dispose the temporary `Image` object created by `Image.FromFile`!

Mystery solved. Apologies for the long, indirect answer, but hopefully it has taught you something about debugging! Do continue to use the solution recommended by mammago, as it is both simple and correct.